# Why do I get exception "connectionFactory must be specified"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-jms

trace:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route FromSAA because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.setUp(RouteService.java:132)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doInitRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2949)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2630)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2649)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at ru.rbru.fms.router.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:156)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1746)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getOrCreateConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:856)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1754)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getOrCreateListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:900)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.configureMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:1582)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:786)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.gatherRootServices(DefaultRoute.java:636)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.gatherServices(DefaultRoute.java:620)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.initializeServices(DefaultRoute.java:205)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doSetup(RouteService.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.setUp(RouteService.java:130)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

My configurations:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IbmMqInitializer {
    private static final String ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_MODE = "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE";

    public void configure(CamelContext context, IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        registerIbmMq(context, ibmMqProperties, connectionFactory);
    }

    private void registerIbmMq(CamelContext context, IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        registerComponent(context, connectionFactory, ibmMqProperties);
    }

    private void registerComponent(CamelContext context,
                                   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                   IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) {
        ComponentsBuilderFactory.jms()
                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .acknowledgementModeName(ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_MODE)
                .concurrentConsumers(ibmMqProperties.getConcurrentConsumersCount())
                .register(context, ibmMqProperties.getQueue());
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private static final Integer CCSID_UTF_8 = 1208;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("resources.ibm.mq.saa")
    public IbmMqProperties saaIbmMqProps() {
        return new IbmMqProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("resources.ibm.mq.esb")
    public IbmMqProperties esbIbmMqProps() {
        return new IbmMqProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory saaIbmMqFactory(@Qualifier("saaIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) throws JMSException {
        return getMqQueueConnectionFactory(ibmMqProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory esbIbmMqFactory(@Qualifier("esbIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) throws JMSException {
        return getMqQueueConnectionFactory(ibmMqProperties);
    }
    
    private ConnectionFactory getMqQueueConnectionFactory(IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) throws JMSException {
        var factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        factory.setCCSID(CCSID_UTF_8);
        factory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        factory.setHostName(ibmMqProperties.getHostName());
        factory.setPort(ibmMqProperties.getPort());
        factory.setChannel(ibmMqProperties.getChannel());
        factory.setQueueManager(ibmMqProperties.getQueueManager());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MqConfiguration {

    private final IbmMqInitializer ibmMqInitializer;

    @Bean
    public CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration(@Qualifier("saaIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties saaIbmMqProps,
                                                          @Qualifier("saaIbmMqFactory") ConnectionFactory saaIbmMqFactory,
                                                          @Qualifier("esbIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties esbIbmMqProps,
                                                          @Qualifier("esbIbmMqFactory") ConnectionFactory esbIbmMqFactory) {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
                try {
                    ibmMqInitializer.configure(context, saaIbmMqProps, saaIbmMqFactory);
                    ibmMqInitializer.configure(context, esbIbmMqProps, esbIbmMqFactory);
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to connect to MQ", e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I use only one ConnectionFactory there is no problem, but as soon as I add one more, e.g.:

```java
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory saaIbmMqFactory(@Qualifier("saaIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) throws JMSException {
        return getMqQueueConnectionFactory(ibmMqProperties);
    }
```

```java
@Service
public class SaaRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public static final String STATUS = "status";

    private final SaaProcessor processor;

    private final IbmMqProperties saaIbmMqProperties;
    private final IbmMqProperties esbIbmMqProperties;

    public SaaRoute(SaaProcessor processor,
                    @Qualifier("saaIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties saaIbmMqProperties,
                    @Qualifier("esbIbmMqProps") IbmMqProperties esbIbmMqProperties) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.saaIbmMqProperties = saaIbmMqProperties;
        this.esbIbmMqProperties = esbIbmMqProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(saaIbmMqProperties.getQueue()).routeId("FromSAA")
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, log, "New message received")
                .process(processor)
                .choice()
                .when(exchange -exchange.getProperty(STATUS).equals(MessageStatus.SUCCESSFULLY_PARSED))
                    .to(esbIbmMqProperties.getQueue())
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Message was not converted")
                .endChoice();
    }
}
```

I get exceptions that mentioned before.

What could cause this exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the camel-jms-starter component, it tries to auto discover the ConnectionFactory. If only one ConnectionFactory object is present in the registry, it is used by default. But when multiple factories are present, it has to be specified on the route using the `connectionFactory` endpoint property.

```
from(jms:destinationType:destinationName? 
      connectionFactory=#saaIbmMqFactory)
      .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, log, "New message received")
      .process(processor)
      .choice()
      .when(exchange -> 
            exchange.getProperty(STATUS)
           .equals(MessageStatus.SUCCESSFULLY_PARSED))
               .to(esbIbmMqProperties.getQueue())
       .otherwise()
               .log("Message was not converted")
       .endChoice();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess now without trying to reproduce the code, I think it is because of the parameters you're passing to the `register` method call in this code

```
private void registerComponent(CamelContext context,
                               ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                               IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties) {
    ComponentsBuilderFactory.jms()
            .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .acknowledgementModeName(ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_MODE)
            .concurrentConsumers(ibmMqProperties.getConcurrentConsumersCount())
            .register(context, ibmMqProperties.getQueue());
}
```

[The doc for the `register` method](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-componentdsl/3.18.1/org/apache/camel/builder/component/ComponentBuilder.html#register(org.apache.camel.CamelContext,java.lang.String)) specifies the second parameter as component name and you're passing your whole queue name. Camel uses component "names" to resolve which component will handle a certain route. So if you write:

```
.to("jms:queueName....")
```

Camel will look up what component is registered with the name "jms" - which is by default the `JmsComponent`, but nothing is stopping you from registering a JmsComponent with a name "myJmsComponent" so you can write:

```
.to("myJmsComponent:queueName")
```

What's happening in your case is you're registering a component with a name of your queue instead of what you think you're doing - registering a different connection factory for a different queues.

If you want to keep using this `ComponentBuilderFactory` pattern what I would suggest is to rewrite your initialiser class like this:

```
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class IbmMqInitializer {
    private static final String ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_MODE = "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE";

    public void configure(CamelContext context, IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String componentName) throws JMSException {
        registerIbmMq(context, ibmMqProperties, connectionFactory, componentName);
    }

    private void registerIbmMq(CamelContext context, IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String componentName) {
        registerComponent(context, connectionFactory, ibmMqProperties, componentName);
    }

    private void registerComponent(CamelContext context,
                                   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
IbmMqProperties ibmMqProperties
                                   String componentName) {
        ComponentsBuilderFactory.jms()
                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .acknowledgementModeName(ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_MODE)
                .concurrentConsumers(ibmMqProperties.getConcurrentConsumersCount())
                .register(context, componentName);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
try {
  ibmMqInitializer.configure(context, saaIbmMqProps, saaIbmMqFactory, "saa");
  ibmMqInitializer.configure(context, esbIbmMqProps, esbIbmMqFactory, "esb");
} catch (JMSException e) {
    log.error("Failed to connect to MQ", e);
}
```

Then change your properties so your method `IbmMqProperties::getQueue()` returns routes starting with `saa:` and `esb:` instead of what you have now, which is probably `jms:...` for both.

So `saa:sourceQueueName` and `esb:destQueueName`.